# TEdit : auto complete and limit minimum number

Tags: delphi

Here is on key press event:

```
procedure TForm3.Edt1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if not(Key in [#8, '0' .. '9']) then
  begin
    memo1.Clear;
    Print('Numbers only !');
    Key := #0;
  end;
  edt1.MaxLength := 12;
end;
```

So here is the story:

I want to auto complete my TEdit. 
Every time i type on TEdit, it will auto complete my (any) numbers. Just fill it with '0' after the first number, and it will be replaced as the second number is typed... and stop on max length (was set to 12).

```
procedure TForm3.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var key : Char;
begin
if Trim(edt1.Text) = '' then
  begin
    memo1.Clear;
    Print('Please input your number');
    Exit
  end;
// Text number CAN NOT LESS than 12 digits. I think it's better with auto-complete.
end;
```

Comment: I cannot make anything of this. I certainly cannot discern the question.

Comment: My edit box allows only numbers. Maximum length is 12 digits. Whenever i insert any number to it, i want to make that number will followed by ZERO. (eg. i type 9, auto-complete is 900000000000) Just fill with '0' until it reach 12 digits.

Comment: Take a look a TMaskEdit instead. It may be what you need...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [`TMaskEdit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Mask.TMaskEdit) with an [`EditMask`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Mask.TMaskEdit.EditMask) of `000000000000;0;0` will do exactly what you want, without your having to write the code and deal with things like <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, or <kbd>LeftArrow</kbd><kbd>RightArrow</kbd> keys.

[image: TMaskEdit Input Mask Editor]